# using apostrophe cms for decoupled single page app

Tags: angular, vue.js, single-page-application, apostrophe, keystone

I'm building a single page app in the style of http://china.fathom.info/

I want to decouple the CMS from the presentation (likely done in Vue or Angular), and consume data from a JSON API. The client wants to use Drupal, but may be able to be persuaded towards something easier and more optimal for our decoupled context (i.e. we're not using backend templating and routing anyway, so why use Drupal?).

I've looked at Keystone which seems a good alternative, but not as full featured as Apostrophe (roles, image upload handling, etc.). The SPA I'm building will be 'database driven' in the sense of creating experience-rich dynamic views based on user requests, rather than being a glorified static site with a CMS (as the Apostrophe demo movies seem to show). I like the ease of editing content via Apostrophe, and the robustness of its features, but the layout options and whole 'edit in place' idea seem incompatible with a decoupled, dynamic SPA?

Does anyone have any experience to offer on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe-headless package will allow you to access APIs for objects that you create in Apostrophe. With that package, you would be free to use whatever front-end framework you like, which would be able to consume the REST endpoints provided by Apostrophe.

You would also still be able to use the built-in Apostrophe editor modals - you could give logged-in users (or certain users) access to a page where they can get to the Apostrophe menus.

---

More information about the headless package here:
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless

Comment: great, just what I was looking for, thank you. any thoughts on this solution vs. going the Drupal's REST API route?
would content then be edited 'in place' on the page, or via a more Druapl-style 'admin' panel for 'content types'?

Comment: I would prefer to use Apostrophe, but that seems like more of a personal taste question. I have appreciated Apostrophe's schema creation and object editing, which only require you to create a schema in order to define a new object, then dynamically creates editors with the appropriate fields. With Apostrophe, you could either do in place editing, or editing via api - there's a lot of flexibility in this case. Even with the headless module, you will be able to use the built-in "admin panel" to edit/create objects, if you choose to go that route.